# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout setting section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior page programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am implementing a `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` and using

```
section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .groupPagingCentered
```

to scroll a section horizontally.

This lets a user scroll from page to page in a section horizontally.

I use

```
section.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = {...}
```

to get the page a user scrolls to.

How can I scroll to a page in this section programmatically?

Comment: Unclear what your use of the invalidation handler is for, or what "preset programmatically" means. Configuring groups programmatically is the normal way.

Comment: better to understand now?

Comment: Yes! I _think_ there is no way to do it. I understand the use of invalidation handler now too; it is just a workaround. Apple needs to give us a much better API for this.

Answer (score -1):

I actually got it working. This code works XCode 12 Beta 2 / Target iOS14 / Swift 5.1.

In this piece of code, pay special attention to spacing, insets and orthogonalScrollingBehavior !!!

```
fileprivate func configureCollectionViewLayout() {
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        self.collectionView.canCancelContentTouches = false
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
            (sectionIndex: Int, layoutEnvironment: NSCollectionLayoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            
            guard let sectionKind = Section(rawValue: sectionIndex) else { return nil }
            let spacing = CGFloat(10)

            switch sectionKind {
            case .someOtherSection:
                // configure the layout for this section
            case .yetAnotherSection:
                // configure the layout for this section
            case .sectionWithOrthogonalScrollingBehaviour:
                let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
                let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
                let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0*9.0/16.0))
                let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
                let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
                group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(0) // should (probably) be 0 otherwise there is an offset when scrollingToIndex
                section.interGroupSpacing = 0 // should (probably) be 0 otherwise there is an offset when scrollingToIndex
                section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0) // leading and trailing should (certainly) be 0 otherwise the pages are offsetted in relation to the view
                section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous // should be continous, otherwise it won't work
                return section
            }
        }
        return layout
    }
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = createLayout()
}
```

To scroll programatically, I implemented a segmented control. When user taps on a segment, the orthogonally scrolling section scrolls automatically to the cell corresponding with the selected segment.

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    
    // determine which Item belongs to the selected segment. In my case Items in a Section are represented by an enum called 'Item'

    let dataSourceIndexPath = self.dataSource.indexPath(for: .itemCase)
    let pressentationIndexPath = self.collectionView.presentationIndexPath(forDataSourceIndexPath: dataSourceIndexPath)! // This step is necessary, otherwise the next line does not have have wanted behaviour (I'm force unwrapping here to simplify. Don't do that in your final code)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: pressentationIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true) // make sure you use .centeredHorizontally
}
```

I'm not sure this is how Apple intended this to be used. It might brake again in next Xcode beta versions.

> Sidenote: In case you were wondering why I need/want a segmented
> control to scroll a collection view: It's because the content of the
> cells in the orthogonally scrolling section need to consume the
> horizontal pan gestures (the cells are all charts that you can move your finger
> along and then display the chart value at the touched location).
> Yes... I know this can also be done in other ways, but I wanted to use
> the compositional layout because it fits together nicely with the
> other sections, and I wanted to keep this sweet built in animation of
> the orthogonalscrollbehavior (even though this is now partially lost because orthogonalScrollingBehavior needs to be .continues for it to work) and I just wanted to see if it can be done :)